# Background Transfer/ Download in IOS When app need to call sequential API more then 1 hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to call 180 sequential serial GET request (After completion on one request will fire another request) and response time is 32 sec for each request, when App is in background mode and user locked iPhone.  180 * 32 = 5760 seconds == 96 min.

I have tried with NSURLSessionDataTask, after calling approx 120 request it will be in suspended state or some times iOS kills app itself.
FYI, App is using VOIP and BLE services

Comment: almost a year ago, i had a very similar situation in a iOS analytic app. the solution was to use background services (in my case, location update always). that kept app running in background for maximum time with high priority. but os can terminal if other apps needed memory. i have tested the solution for more than 5 hours in background, running all the task(mostly api hits)

Comment: Did you use NSURLSessionDataTask ? Can you please share your exact code here... Might be I am doing some silly mistake

Comment: No, it uses NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest.

Comment: Would you add the code you have tried, Anurag?